# Need an explanation of my app's behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lifecycle

I've created a service that counts in the background. I'm starting the service in my MainActivity's onCreate().

Whenever i restart my app, so does my service class by setting the timer to -1. However, when I switch the orientation of my phone the timer does not reset.

As far is I know, killing an app calls the onDestroy() method and starting it up again afterwards calls the onCreate(). I've read that changing orientation calls the same two methods, so why is it that the two actions result in different behaviors, and is there any way to prevent it? My code expects the timer to reset when the app is killed, so when the orientation is changed, my timer is way off.

Here is the code of my service class:

```
ublic class CounterService extends Service {
private Handler handler;
private int time = -1;
private boolean isActive;
private Intent timeBroadcaster;
private Runnable counter;
private Thread serviceCounter;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "TIME";

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();
    timeBroadcaster = new Intent();

    timeBroadcaster.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SessionLogger_Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();


    counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                isActive = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isInteractive();
                if (isActive) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    time += 1;
                    Log.i("TIME", String.valueOf(time));
                } else {
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
                    if (time > 5) {
                        //log
                    }
                    time = 0;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            timeBroadcaster.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);
            sendBroadcast(timeBroadcaster);

        }
    };

    serviceCounter = new Thread(counter);
    serviceCounter.start();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rotation doesn't kill the app.  It kills the Activity.  THe application still runs, but the Activity is restarted.  Since the Application still runs, any Services in the app are still running, and Services are not restarted.  In fact that's the entire point of a Service-  to remain running even when Activities are killed.